# Will a manual installation from python 3.4.1 source properly overwrite Ubuntu's existing python 3.4 install?

Tags: python-3.x, apt-get

I installed python3.4 with "apt-get install" on Ubuntu. Will manually installing python 3.4.1 from source properly overwrite the apt-get install of python 3.3?

For example, the Ubuntu install has files in /usr/lib/python3.4, whereas the installer in https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tar.xz deposits files in several other places.

How can I properly remove the apt-get install? Or will the source install properly overwrite the old directories?

Answer (score 0):

remove with `apt-get remove (package)`. Example with `hello`:

```
# sudo apt-get remove hello

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  hello
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 245 not upgraded.
After this operation, 111 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 211551 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing hello ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
```

Get the source, which has has the right paths -- it's been Debianized (for Ubuntu also)

```
$ apt-get source hello
```

Go into the source and build a binary package for it

```
$ cd hello*
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

Then install the freshly made binary package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../hello*deb

Selecting previously unselected package hello.
(Reading database ... 211546 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking hello (from ../hello_2.8-4_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up hello (2.8-4) ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Or, install the Ubuntu(Debian) Python 3.4.1 binary package from here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3